# By mistake exectuted "sudo chmod -R -x * && sudo chmod -R +X *" command

Tags: permissions, chmod

By mistake I executed this command on Ubuntu 16.04

```
sudo chmod -R -x * && sudo chmod -R +X *
```

Now all the folder converted into files, which is not opening.

How can I fix it?

Comment: in which folder did you execute the command?

Comment: In addition to that ^, the second `chmod` probably never ran, since `chmod` would show an error because it couldn't descend into any directories on which it had already set `-x`.

Comment: @Yaron at root of my login

Comment: See the link(https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2237478) for same case, but my systems Documents sub-folders get converted.

Comment: Do you have backup to your documents? Home folder?

Comment: Root of your login? Your home directory? Or / ?

Comment: (Unimportantly, I don't think `chmod +X` actually does anything? It has to be a small `x` afaik?)

Comment: @Zanna adds execute to directories and keeps it for files which already have it, iirc

Answer (score 0):

You have removed execution-rights (and thereby access to) all directories and eventually files that where executable.

Start by giving back exec to directories:

```
find . -type d -exec chmod +x {} \;
```

If you had any executable programs, then for each of these do:

```
chmod +x filename
```

The `+x`in the commands above gives execute rights to all (user, group and others - the three different access levels in a linux/posix filesystem)). If you for some reason needs to restrict access to only user or user+group you can replace `+x` with `u+x` or `ug+x` to achieve this.

Comment: what do you mean "eventually"? Shouldn't OP start by giving `x` only to u?

Comment: @Zanna, you are right .. I will change the text.

Comment: Perhaps you could investigate which directories should not have `x` for u - I attempted it in my answer here [Home files and folders permissions could not be determined](//askubuntu.com/a/854533)

Comment: @Zanna .. I think that it is more relevant to identify directories that should ONLY have `x` for u .. but besides that, you are right.